# Is there a way to enable debug log for javax.naming.ldap package on production environment?

Tags: java, ldap

We are using InitialLdapContext class of ldap package and providing the property's map to it to make a connection with LDAP. Our Customer is sometime loosing connection with LDAP and there are no logs captured for the issue. So we want to See the Ldap logs for the issue.
We are using Log4j for logging purpose.